# Cannot find a User Assigned Managed Identities in AAD's enterprise applications

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have a few User Assigned Managed Identities in my Azure Subscription.

When I go to Azure AD blade -> Enterprise Applications and search for any of the User Assigned Managed Identities, by either name or Object ID, I am not able to fine them:

[image]

Why I am not able to find User Assigned Managed Identities by name like I can do for other enterprise applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I created one **User Assigned Managed Identity** with ***same*** name as below:

[image]

When I tried to find it in **Enterprise Applications** blade, it's not there like below:

[image]

To get the results, you need to change the filter to **`Application type == Managed Identities`** like below:

[image]

When I checked now, I am able to find the required **identity** successfully like below:

[image]

So, make sure to change the **filters** to get the results.